# Simple directive not working in Cloud9?

Tags: angularjs, cloud9-ide

I seem not to be able to redo a simple directive tutorial in cloud9. Basically it does not produce the output "Here I am to save the day".

**main2.js**

```
var app = angular.module("superhero", []);

app.directive("superman", function() {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: "<div>Here I am to save the day</div>"
}
})
```

This function is loaded in the index file here as shown below. In addition I have another file called main.js where I declare the app "myApp", but even removing that does not help.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>My AngularJS App</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  <script src="bower_components/html5-boilerplate/js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


  <div ng-app="superhero">
    <superman></superman>
  </div>


  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <script src="main2.js"></script>
  <script src="view1/view1.js"></script>
  <script src="view2/view2.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: See this plunk, it works: http://plnkr.co/edit/h37VCUZ2lQsFV3FtRReX?p=preview perharps c9 is returning an error on console, look out for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the main2.js script (and the angular files) before

```
<div ng-app="superhero">
    <superman></superman>
</div>
```

I tried in jsfiddle.net and it only appears to work when the javascript is loaded in the head of the page before the HTML.